# How to protected routes on client side in Nextjs and redirect if don't have admin role?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

Now, I have user role in Context. I can check the role of context in useEffect on each page before fetch data and redirect to login if the user doesn't have the admin role:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo.role == 2) {
        getPosts(pagerInfo.currentPage);
    } else {
        Router.push('/login');
    }
    
}, []);
```

But I don't want to rewrite to check the user role on each page. How can I use it for every page?

Answer (score 0):

Do it once in a top-level component, such as `_app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write a higher order component, which takes a component as an argument, you apply some conditions and based on satisfied conditions you either allow or reject the access.

```
const withAuth = (Component) => (role) => {
  // those props will be passed to HOC when you use this. 
  return (props) => {
    //here you write your code to get the data
    if (userInfo.role == 2) {
        return <Component user={data} loading={loading} {...props} />;

   } else {
      Router.push('/login');
   }      
  };
};
```

some of your pages are going to be public and some of them will be private. So will connect the private pages to this HOC.

```
// i pass two props to show how to use them
const OnlyAdmin = ({user, loading}) => {
  return (
    <BaseLayout  loading={loading}>      
      <h1>I am Admin Page - Hello {user.name}</h1>
    </BaseLayout>
  )
}

export default withAuth(OnlyAdmin)('admin');
```

Comment: I've tried, but get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined 
You can see here: https://imgur.com/a/rcsLvLd

Comment: You can see detail here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17397

Comment: "children" is not defined becasuse you did not pass the props to the component. const AdminPublishedPosts: NextPage = (PROPSSSS) => {
    return (
        <AdminLayout>
            <AdminPublishedPostsContainer />
        </AdminLayout>
    );
};

Comment: So, will I do something after pass the props? ('props' is declared but its value is never read)